# Find "important" entries in a sorted log

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have a log file consisting of several thousand integers, each separated onto a new line. I've parsed this into an array of such integers, also sorted. Now my issue becomes finding the "important" integers from this log--these are ones that show up some user-configurable portion of the time.

For example, given the log, the user can filter to only see entries that appear a certain scaled number of times.

Currently I'm scanning the whole array and keeping count of the number of times each entry appears. Surely there is a better method?

Comment: Why not store the counts when you store the numbers? Memory is cheap.

Comment: If there are long runs of identical numbers then binary search can find the end of the run in a time quicker than a linear scan over the run. Another idea, when you encounter a new number you can skip a certain distance to see if it is the same number. If not -- it isn't important (and any skipped number isn't important) though the number you skipped to might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I need to note that the following is just a theoretical solution, and you probably should use what is proposed by @MBo.

Take every `m = n / l`th element of the sorted array. Only those elements can be important, as no sequence of identical elements of length `m` can fit between `i*m` and `(i+1)*m`.

For each element `x`, find with binary search its lower bound and upper bound in the array. Subtracting indexes, you can know count, and decide to keep or discard `x` as unimportant.

Total complexity would be `O((n/m) * log n) = O(l * log n)`. For large `m` it could be (asymptotically) better than `O(n)`. To get an improvement in practice, however, you need very specific circumstances:

- Array is given to you presorted (otherwise just use counting sort and you get an answer immediately)
- You can access `i`-th element of the array in `O(1)` *without reading the whole array*. Otherwise, again, use counting sort with hash table.

Lets assume you have a file consisting of *sorted fixed-width integers* `"data.bin"` (it is possible for variable width too, but requires some extra effort). Then in pseudocode, algorithm could be something like so:

```
def find_all_important(l, n):
  m = n / l
  for i = m to l step m:
    x = read_integer_at_offset("data.bin", i)
    lower_bound = find_lower_bound(x, 0, i)
    upper_bound = find_upper_bound(x, i, n)
    if upper_bound - lower_bound >= m:
      report(x)

def find_lower_bound(x, begin, end):
  if end - begin == 0:
    return begin
  mid = (end + begin) / 2
  x = read_integer_at_offset("data.bin", mid)
  if mid < x:
    return find_lower_bound(x, mid + 1, end)
  else:
    return find_lower_bound(x, begin, mid)
```

As a guess, you will not gain any noticeable improvement compared to naive `O(n)` on modern hardware, unless your file is very large (hundreds of MBs). And of course it is viable if your data can't fit in RAM. But as always with optimization, it might be worth testing.

Answer (score 0):

Your sorting takes O(NlogN) time perhaps. Do you need to make (n/I) queries many times for the same data set?

If yes, walk through sorted array, make `(Value;Count)` pairs and sort them by `Count` field. Now you can easily separate pairs with high counts with binary search

Comment: OK, so the first sorting stage is not needed. And the second sorting works with potentially smaller array size (if repetitions are frequent)